# Jquery mobile UI input dropdown formatting behaviour in tables

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, html-table

I have two problems relating to using Jquery mobile UI framework dropdown selectors when inside table rows that I am hoping for assistance with

The first relates to the row height. When I put a drop-down selector in a row (that is otherwise formatted identically to surrounding rows), it makes the row height significantly larger than all the other rows - example html and image of the behavior below;

```
<tr>
<td class="leftcol">
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<select name="updown" id="updown">
  <option value="THP (psi)">THP (psi)</option>
  <option value="FBHP (psi)">BHP (psi)</option>
</select>
</div>
</td>
<td><input id=thp size="7"  type="number" style="width:85%" value="300" required></td></tr>
```

[image: Resultant row height behaviour as rendered in iPhone shown below]

The second issue I have (with the same data) is that when I turn the phone to landscape, while the tables stretch out nicely, the dropdown list description actually truncates (gets smaller) cutting off some of the value which was otherwise displayed ok in portrait mode - any idea how to prevent?
[image: Resultant table rendering in landscape mode with iPhone]

Comment: FYI - I'm using the latest 1.01 Jquery Mobile build

Comment: Cant really say too much without looking at the CSS. Any chance of getting a look at this? Are you using the default jquery mobile css? Do you have any custom css?

Comment: Thanks - no just using standard jquery mobile css (jquery.mobile-1.0.1.css) along with the associated docs css (jqm-docs.css). The only customization I have made relates to table background color, setting the alternating color bands you see above with example code as #table1   tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color: #A3B9D2;} and #table1    tbody tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: #E7EDF3;}. If you like I can fwd privately a link to a staging website to play with the live code :-)

Comment: That might be a good idea my email is dkarzon  at  tboda.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, look like both your issues are to do with the `<div data-role="fieldcontain">`

It applies a class ("ui-field-contain") which has a 1em vertical margin and theres some media queries to change the width depending on the screen width.

Take out that dive and you should be good.

Comment: Beautiful - thanks. I just took the example code that the Jquery mobile UI team suggested as necessary for the dropdown - I didn't think to question whether all the bits were needed. Thanks again.